# Bootstrap star rating onclick dont fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I have a for loop that has a lot of divs. For each div I have evaluation with the star rating, I'm trying to trigger the onclick event but it doesn't work. I already tryed the `.live` event it still didn't work. I just can't fire the onclick event with all the options that I already saw here on stackoverflow.

**Here is my code and the script**

```
           <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:40px">
                <input name="input-2" value="0" class="rating-loading input-2" data-size="xs">
            </div>


 $('.input-2').live('click', function () {
 console.log("a");


});
```

Comment: Can you share more info please.. Such as errors ? Maybe a JSFIDDLE ? Also your input has no `type`

Comment: in this case, that i tryed, it says that live is not a function, i saw many answers working with live on stackoverflow

Comment: Set id attribute for each input with unique value.

Answer (score 2):

if you inspect element after page loads, you don't click on .input-2 you click on .rating so easiest way would be like this

`$('.rating').on('click',function(){
   console.log("a");
});`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's `live()` function is deprecated. You should use `$(el).click(function)` or `$(el).on('click', function)`

Comment: click event is not working, i tryed aswell, but it detect onchange event i discovered now, the thing is, i want to pass the own value of the input to the server, can i do it just using html? like with "this"?                                                           <input onchange="location.href='@Url.Action("EstrelasAvaliacao", "Solucoes", new {estrela = this,id=i.SolucaoId})'" name="input-2" value="0" class="rating-loading input-2" data-size="xs">

Comment: You may want to use data attributes. Check out this fiddle and see if it helps [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxmjnxry/)

Answer (score 0):

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.star').on('click',function(){
                console.log("a");
         });
```

Comment: This answer came in low quality post. Add some explanation even though code is self explanatory